# "Joan walked out and has left her bag"

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

> (1) Joan walked out and has left her bag

It seems that (1) is not good because it violates a tense agreement rule. Is that right?  Then, I am wondering what differences there exist between sentence (1) above and sentence (2) below.

> (2) Tom moved to New York five years ago and has lived there since then.

Comment: It's not just a matter of saying your "Joan" example violates ***tense agreement***. The reason the "Tom" example works is because Present Perfect ***has lived there*** specifically refers to the entire time between Tom moving to NY and the present time of speaking (something that started in the past has continued until now). But in the "Joan" example, she only left her bag behind ***once*** (at the same time as leaving) - there's no sense of ***continuing to leave the bag, right up until time of speaking.***

Comment: ...for a more "borderline" case, consider *John caught Covid and **was / has been** admitted to hospital*. Where the Present Perfect version pragmatically entails that John must *currently* still be in hospital, but with the Simple Past version he might have recovered and been discharged (or he might even have *died* by the time of speaking; it's "agnostic" on that score).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Present perfect can refer to finished single events in the past, so long as they have a present result, and that present result is the focus of the clause. "I've lost my keys" is a single event in the past, and it means, "I'm missing my keys right now."

Comment: @gotube: That's all perfectly true, but I don't see how it relates to the fact that OP's "Joan" example isn't really idiomatically valid. OIC - you don't think there's anything wrong with it!

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't think it is difficult to come up with a situation in which the present perfect in the "Joan"example makes a sense. Assume that, in the middle of conversation with others, Joan got a call and walked out of the meeting room, without taking her bag with her, that she has not come back to the room for the bag until now, and that her bag is therefore still in the meeting room. In such a situation, do you think the "Joan" example sentence above sounds good?

Comment: @SunnyLee: I'm certainly not suggesting OP's text is *syntactically* invalid - just that it's "not really" idiomatic. Maybe in your relatively contrived context, the juxtaposition of Simple Past and Present Perfect conjoined by ***and*** would pass muster, but to be honest I still don't really like it. I'd most likely change the conjunction to ***but*** as well as maintaining the parallel verb forms: *Joan walked out **but she** left her bag.* OR use the Perfect ONCE, FIRST: *Joan **has** walked out **but she** left her bag* if it was important to stress "current relevance"

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks for your comment. Your sentence 'Joan walked out but she left her bag' surely sounds much better, in fact, perfectly good. What I am interested in is why the OP's Joan example sounds odd. (A book on linguistics states that the Joan example sentence 'sounds very strange'. but does not give any explanation about the strangeness.) As you stated, the sentence seems neither to be syntactically bad, nor to be semantically wrong. I would be very grateful if you would give any opinion regarding it. Thanks again.

Comment: I think the "Joan" example is a form of [zeugma](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/zeugma#:~:text=A%20zeugma%20is%20a%20literary,you're%20using%20a%20zeugma.). Without the Perfect, both actions (walking out, and leaving the bag) both happened in the past, which makes it reasonable to link them using ***and***. And because it's quite natural in English to start with a Perfect, then drop back to Simple Past, *Joan **has** walked out and left her bag* is fine too. But ***and*** is too "weak" a link to fluently tie together Past ***walked out*** and "Present" ***bag is [still] left behind***.

Comment: Many thanks for your comments, everyone. I enjoyed and learned a lot. I am still wondering what in the Joan example caused the zeugma effect. Thank You All.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence about Joan is good. There's no rule against having different tenses, so long as they make sense. An easy example to demonstrate this is, "I'**ve been** to Tahiti twice and **would love** to see it again."

The *present perfect* tense has several different functions, and one difference between your two sentences is the function. Your sentence about Joan has the function of *"a finished event in the past that has a present effect"*. Your sentence about Tom has the function of, *"a continuous event that began in the past and continues to the present"*.

Another difference is that the Joan sentence also has a simple past tense. Normally, a simple past verb must have a finished time for when it happened. In "Joan walked out and has left her bag", "walked out" provides the context for "has left her bag", so it takes the implied time frame of "recently" from "has left her bag". It could be rephrased with both verbs in the present perfect:

> Joan has walked out and left her bag.

(Here, though "left" is on its own and looks like simple past, it's actually the past participle, forming present perfect by sharing the "has" with "walked out".)

Comment: Downvote with no comment :'(

Comment: But the original sentence is **Joan walked out**, I would've said "**Joan** (has) **walked out, leaving** her bag behind" I would not associate "walked out" with "has left" something. it would be like saying "**Joan swam** [in the race] and **has won** first prize" Nope, does't work at all.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, in writing but in speaking it would be the way it is. But there are all sorts of ways to say these things and this one is actually grammatical. I think your swimming example does in fact work fine. Of course, one could use simple past in both or present perfect in both.

Comment: I would not get too heavily into the grammar per se but rather into spoken English. And how people really speak. That said, I don't disagree with your answer. Joan walked out [five minutes ago or as a finished action] and has left her bag. [true at the time of speaking.]